# Not able to import font-awesome in Reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to use `font-awesome` in my Reactjs project but I have problem importing it.

Have installed it

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

Imported it in my index.js file

```
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

**webpack.config.js**

Added loader to my webpack

```
{
  test: /font-awesome\.config\.js/,
  use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        { loader: 'font-awesome-loader' }
       ]
}
```

And then tried to use it in my code

```
<a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

What loader should I use instead of one I did?

Comment: what is this `test: /font-awesome\.config\.js/,` suppose to do?

Comment: `test` should match the files to transform

Comment: this is recommended way to install Font Awesome in React projects > https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

Comment: ` test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/` @marzelin should put it like this. To match the files. My mistake. Don't have error any more but still not showing right `<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>`

Comment: have you imported `font-awesome` module at the top of your app?

Comment: @marzelin yes, with `import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'; ` in my index.js file

Comment: what about this: `require("font-awesome-loader!./path/to/font-awesome.config.js");` ?

Comment: @ballbern have tried it but even using that way can't get ` <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i> ` to display.

Comment: @marzelin it says `Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome-loader'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [React implementation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) of FontAwsome:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faAngleDoubleDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

...

render() {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleDown} pulse />
  )
}
```

You can use the desired animation with adding `pulse` or `spin` boolean prop.

Comment: I have also tried that. But how should I add icon that I want. For example here `faStroopwafel` is added like `library.add(faStroopwafel)` How should I add  `<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>` and display it?

Comment: The library I recommended was a deprecated solution. I fixed my example. You can now use any icon simply using the CamelCase version of the name, like `faAngleDoubleDown`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works now. Probably that's why it didn't work for me first time. Thanks mate!